# Is it possible to have a custom post type with feed but without the archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, feed, custom-post-type-archives

In Wordpress 3.9.2 I couldn't find the way to have a custom post type which would have the feed permalink like this:

> example.com/custom-post-type/feed/

But **didn't** show the archive (show 404) for:

> example.com/custom-post-type/

Just for the sake of completeness it should display the single post:

> example.com/custom-post-type/post-1

The relevant `$args` I've tried to change:

```
    $args = array(
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'rewrite'             => array('slug' => 'custom-post-type', 'feeds' => true, 'feed' => true),
```

My research shows that when the `has_archive` is set to `false`, the feed doesn't work.

Comment: You could always [add your own feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed), just copy the [RSS Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds#Customizing_Feed_Templates) and modify it to your CPT.

Comment: From quick look at a source feed rewrite rules _are_ chained to it having archive pretty tight. :\ Not sure if recreating them separately would be enough to make it work.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thanks for the input, but I'm not sure it's the right direction (or I might misunderstood what you're suggesting) - the point is to use the existing feeds not to create new ones.

Comment: @Rarst I have exaclty the same impression.

Comment: I am coming to the same conclusions, `has_archive => true` seems to be required. I will be playing with the rewrite rules next, for a great little plugin to help troubleshoot and visually see which rewrite rules get applied have a look at [Moneyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/)